# How to know if click event originated outside div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a button is clicked, it triggers the function that does the following:

```
function doThings() {
   1. display an overlay
   2. display table on top of overlay
   3. assign event for table click
   4. assign event for everything else BUT table click
}
```

The idea for `4.` is to handle clicks that originated anywhere *except* inside my `table`, or more specifically, inside my `table-div`. Here is what I tried:

```
function doThings() {
   // 1. display an overlay
   // 2. display table on top of overlay
   // 3. assign event for table click (interaction happens here)

   // 4.
   $("body").not( ".table-div" ).click(function(e) {
       // hide my overlay and stop interaction
   });
}
```

The problem is that when `4.` is added, the interaction coded in part `3.` does not begin when my button is clicked. I also tried this:

```
   // 4.
   $("body").click(function(e) {
      if ( ! (e.target.class == "table-div" || $(e.target).parents(".table-div").size()) ) { 
         // hide my overlay and stop interaction
      }
   });
```

Neither of them works. I assume there is a conflict between `body` click event and `table-div` click event, but I am not sure how to resolve it. Is there a way to make this work? Thank you!

Comment: can you please share your code or create a fiddle for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that I guess you need to have event propagation to be stopped with:

```
 event.stopPropagation();
```

At #3 you need to use it.

At #3. As the events are tend to bubble up and you have not handled it. *seems likely*. So, all you need is event propagation to be handled. Which stops the event to bubble up.

---

That should be like this:

```
   $( ".table-div" ).click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // <---here
```

Comment: I tried this at #3, but it didn't affect anything. If I remove #4, part #3 works perfectly. Once #4 is introduced, part #3 stops working without any runtime errors.

Comment: Have you passed the event in the callback parameters of the click event?